# Access/Change the html of a class in another webpart on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, dom, sharepoint-2007

I have a div `class='myDiv'` in a webpart on my page. I need to access that div from another webpart on the page I wish to use javascript/jquery to do so. Since they are not inside of the same page utility I cannot directly select it with jquery for example:
    `$('.myDiv').hide()`.
 How can I find this div in the other webpart from the webpart I am working in on the same page

Comment: What do you mean by "webpart" and why can't you access one from the other?

Comment: I should have specified in the tags; moss 2007

Comment: Why can you not select it with `.myDiv`? Does SharePoint change class names? Once it's on the client, it doesn't matter if it's from different webparts, it's all in the DOM and should be accessible

Comment: You would think it would be but for some reason when I call the function which I have tied to the click of an image on the webpart which does not contain the div `$('.myDiv').hide()` nothing happens.  When I call the same function inside of the webpart that contains the div it disappears with no problem I believe it has something to do with parent/child relationship but I am not sure.

Comment: little bit confused. Do you mean to say that the webpart which is trying to acces the div are in different pages?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to give a ID for the div control and access else use below javascript to get that control.

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
    var j = h[i].id;
    if (j.indexOf('file') > 0) {
        alert(j);
    }
}
```